# Cyborg Movie from 1980s or 1990s

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find out the name of a cyborg movie from the 1980s or 1990s. In the movie, a guy either works in a lab or he's a cop; I can't remember which. I'm pretty sure he works in a lab, though. Anyway, I remember that he's turned into a cyborg and he looks scary. Half of his face is still human, but the other half is cyborg, and I think his cyborg eye glows red.

A woman gets kidnapped, (she's his lover or she worked in the same lab, or both), and the cyborg guy tries to save her.

The film takes place in the city, and I remember a scene where the cyborg and the woman are in a car, and the cyborg sees his face in the mirror for the first time. Towards the end of the movie, there's a scene where these characters are in a church or something.

**What movie is this?**

Comment: Who the hell voted to close this as too broad? There's loads of info here, more than enough to uniquely identify it.

Comment: Robocop if you turn his helment 90 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 7):

Could this be the big-budget blockbuster "[Eliminators](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091003/)" from 1986?

The titular hero is a half-faced android with a red glowing eye. The film opens in a large laboratory where we see his creation.

On the downside, there's no scene set in a car. He's too large to fit, but later in the movie he does disconnect from the tank and walk around on his own.

Comment: No, that's not it. The film I'm looking for happened entirely in the city.

Comment: How could that possibly not be it?  It has a character called "Mandroid".  And Denise Crosby.  This is everything anyone could want in a film.

Comment: Oh, man. This movie looks awful.

Comment: @IconDaemon - It's actually worth watching. But mainly so that the next time you see a bad film, you can say to yourself "*At least I'm not watching Eliminators*"

Comment: They recycled the robot from The Black Hole!

Comment: Mandroid! Now I see what see why she quite TNG; Data has nothing on this guy.

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for *[The Vindicator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092172/)* (also known as RoboMan), a 1986 film featuring David McIlwraith as a Carl, a cyborg made with human parts and a next-generation space suit.

Carl discovers a conspiracy at his lab and is murdered by the company, kept alive and experimented upon. He awakens and, regains consciousness and breaks control away from the facilities computers, and seeks to reveal the conspiracy and reunite with his wife. During his escape, the outer layer of the space suit is burned off, revealing the cyborg components.

Along the way, an assassin named Hunter played by Pam Grier attempts to recapture Carl, and it is revealed that the company has used the same cyborg process to three other cadavers which are used against Carl. Infamously, Hunter brandishes long assassin-needles to be used against her foe during a scene in a car.

[image: Carl raising his visor, revealing intact eyes]

Comment: Wow. This looks almost as good as Eliminators.

Comment: Heresy! Eliminators is on a level that no other file could ever hope to aspire. :-)